# Firefox address bar: How to tab through history without hitting tab twice due to new three-dot button menu?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

With the recent [Firefox 113.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/113.0/releasenotes/) release, there is a new three-dot button menu in the history search results of the Firefox address bar. How can I stop that button from taking focus when pressing the tab key or, alternatively, get rid of it?

It is a circular button with three dots to the right of any search result from my browsing history. Its tooltip says “Open menu”. When you click on it, there are two entries: “Remove from history” and “Learn more”, see following screenshot:

[image: History result menu opened]

I am used to pressing the tab key for going down through the search results. The new menu button makes this more difficult because it takes tab focus. I have to hit the tab key twice to get to the next item. Hitting tab the first time moves the focus to the new button. I only get to the next item when I hit tab a second time. Also, I do not think the menu is helpful to me. I already know how to delete entries from history (Shift+Delete), and “Learn more” is nothing but a link to [How to customize Firefox Suggest settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-suggest). Therefore, I would like to disable this new button or at least stop it from taking tab focus. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) settings related to this feature:

- `browser.urlbar.resultmenu` – turn the feature on or off
- `browser.urlbar.resultmenu.keyboardAccessible` – toggle the menu’s accessibility with the tab key (exactly what I want)

So the configuration options were there all along. The difficulty was finding them, especially since I did not know any specific keywords for identifying the issue in an internet search.

I created a new profile with the [Profile Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) (old profiles can be cluttered with additional *about:config* settings from extensions) to search for possible keywords in *about:config:* “address”, “menu”, and then “bar”. For every one of those, I toggled all the boolean preferences and then checked whether the three-dot menu button was still there. That is how I found the *about:config* settings.

After I had found the *about:config* settings, an internet search for the name of the settings revealed that others had already discussed them:

- [Remove URL bar suggestions additional 3-dot menu : firefox](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/118474f/remove_url_bar_suggestions_additional_3dot_menu/) (Reddit)
- [1813517 - Add browser.urlbar.resultMenu.keyboardAccessible about:config pref for allowing Tab key to skip over the result menu button](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1813517) (Bugzilla)